# SQL: How to show the top value for different Years

Tags: sql, partition

I have a table filled with football scores in different years, and I have been tring to identify which team has the best home record each year and how many home wins they had. I have tried the following code:

````
hometeam,
season,
count(case when FTR = 'H' then 'hw' END) AS 'homewins'
from results
group by HomeTeam, Season
order by homewins desc,  season```
but this does not give me the name of the team with the best record each eay, but instead the best records of all time. any help isa ppreciated (I am still very much a beginner).
 (the seasons continue further down)[Source table attached][1]:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOlMG.png
````

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the sample table is linked  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOlMG.png . The sample results would be 2019- 20 Liverpool 18 Home wins, 2018-19 Manchester City 17 home wins etc

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it, with the results ordered by year and with the highest home win count first.  Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Season NVARCHAR(5), HomeTeam NVARCHAR(20), FTR NVARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('2019','TeamA','H'),('2019','TeamA','H'),('2019','TeamA','H'),
                        ('2019','TeamB','A'),('2019','TeamB','H'),('2019','TeamB','H'),
                        ('2020','TeamA','H'),('2020','TeamA','A'),('2020','TeamA','A'),
                        ('2020','TeamB','H'),('2020','TeamB','H'),('2020','TeamB','H') 

;WITH HomeWins
AS (
    SELECT Season,HomeTeam,CASE WHEN FTR='H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Wins
    FROM #tmp
    )
SELECT Season,HomeTeam,SUM(Wins) AS HomeWins
FROM HomeWins
GROUP BY Season,HomeTeam
ORDER BY Season ASC,SUM(Wins) DESC
```